# WS-Security response message The signature or decryption was invalid

Tags: soap, cxf, soapui, ws-security, wss4j

I'm developing a SOAP service using Apache CXF &   WSS4J for security,which receives  a SOAP service request which are digitally signed message. Testing using SOAP UI   but I'm getting an issue with decrypting and validating the signature. Here is the error message that I'm getting.

```
<faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">ns1:FailedCheck</faultcode>
     <faultstring>The signature or decryption was invalid</faultstring>
```

Comment: Please see if this is helpful - http://blog.lodeblomme.be/2011/09/27/apache-cxf-ws-security-the-signature-or-decryption-was-invalid/

Comment: Check certificate configuration. Are you able to run CXF signature sample ? Try modifying the sample with your certificates.